# Optimization ( More cuts or stretching )

Tags: optimization

I want to make a house model but I am not sure which method to make walls for rooms would be better.

Dragging around already existing edges that have no other purpose, but which are still necessary in the mesh to create a proper edge loop, resulting in a messy mesh but with fewer triangles and vertices.

[image: first solution]

Or cutting up the mesh which would result in higher count of vertices and triangles but edge loops would look nice and tidy

[image: alternative solution]

Comment: It is unclear what your concern is. Could you please edit the question to clarify your goal? Thank you. :)

Comment: Also walls of text are not welcoming for readers trying to help, please use proper spacing.

Comment: Why not make walls as a separate entity? You wouldn't even have to deal with all that funky topology, and end up with a lot less polygons overall